# Cannot output pound symbol to PDF

Tags: c#, itext

I've been trying to open and edit a PDF file using itextsharp.

Everything works absolutely fine however for some reason I cannot write a '£' to the PDF.

When output does generate though, it leaves 'blank space', this has left me puzzled.

Wondering if anyone has come across this before?

This is my code:

```
PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(x);

iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rectangle = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(370, 750, 155, 790);
rectangle.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(Color.FromArgb(147, 146, 152));
cb.Rectangle(rectangle);

BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);
cb.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 21);
cb.BeginText();

var encoder = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(858); //also tried with 437
byte[] c = new byte[] { 156 };
string appendto = "£" + textBox1.Text;

cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, appendto, 245, 764, 0);
cb.EndText();
```

Comment: What are your `encoder` and `c` variables meant to be doing? They're ignored...

Comment: I apologise, I have attempted encoding but to no avail. Still didn't work. I should have edited that out...

Comment: I've inserted \u00A3 to the string, but that's still not done the trick.

Comment: It's this line, but how can I get this line to output a £? The UNICODE works in other output just fine...

cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, appendto, 245, 764, 0);

Comment: You use a standard 14 font (i.e. One of the 14 fonts a PDF viewer has to support our of the box for a given character set. The £ does not seem to be in that character set. You should use a font which contains that symbol and embed the font.

Comment: I've tried this too. Still no success. I even used times_roman in which the £ is definitely a character.

Comment: Sure, the Times Roman you know from Windows has the pound symbol, but are you using the Standard Type 1 font (`BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN`) or the OpenType font with TrueType outlines (`times.ttf`). If the former, your allegation is wrong, if the latter you should show your altered code. Surely you've replaced `CP1250` with `IDENTITY_H` now that you're using Unicode?

Comment: Stupidly not. And that's done it. I will update my answer below. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Bruno pointed out, I had to change the CP1250 to IDENTITY_H and embed the font.

```
 PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(x);
                        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rectangle = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(370, 750, 140, 790);
                        rectangle.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(Color.FromArgb(147, 146, 152));
                        cb.Rectangle(rectangle);

                        BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("times.ttf"/*BaseFont.HELVETICA*/, /*BaseFont.CP1250*/ BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED/*BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED*/);
                        cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);
                        cb.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 21);
                        cb.BeginText();

                        string appendto = "\u00A3" + textBox1.Text;

                        if (!checkBox1.Checked)
                        {
                            cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, appendto, 235, 764, 0);
                        }
                        else if (checkBox1.Checked)
                        {
                            cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, appendto, 260, 764, 0);
                        }
                        cb.EndText();
```